# How to fix laggy behavior in Auctionsieve 2.6.7 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: java

With **Auctionsieve 2.6.7** on **Ubuntu 14.04**, when I move the pointer around with the mouse, the user interface is laggy.

A shady gray color is **slowly** painted across discrete rows of the screen from left to right ("**row-highlighter**").  This behavior makes Auctionsieve much slower to use.  The developer of Auctionsieve responded to me on Auctionsieve forums (6/21/2014).  He said he suspects "a weird combination of window manager, GPU driver, and JAVA", and suggested that I try Java 8.

At this time, OpenJDK 8 is not in the Ubuntu repositories, and I don't want to destabilize my system by installing it by some other means (e.g. PPA).  I am not a Ubuntu expert, and I am trying to keep things simple, as well as keep my OS clean and stable.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and overcome it?